# Fold selected code in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I fold an arbitrary block of code in intellij?

I know there is the cmd+. shortcut, but that only works if the selection is within a single line.

Answer (score 6):

`Cmd + '.'`, or on Windows `Ctrl + '.'` shortcut indeed folds and unfolds selected block of code. If no code is selected, it folds the method in which the cursor is placed.

When you have cursor inside a method, you can fold/unfold entire method by `Ctrl + '+'`/`Ctrl + '-'`. The extensions of this combination are `Ctrl + Shift + '+'` and `Ctrl + Shift + '-'`, which fold/unfold all methods and comments in active file.

Answer (score 0):

Press `Strg+A` (search for action) and search for `Fold Selection`. My shortcut is `Ctrl+.`. I don't know if this is the default short cut for that action.

This will fold your selection. If there is no selection, the surrounding code block will be folded.

Comment: You are correct. Fold Selection is what he is looking for, I misunderstood the question.